# elasticsearch client with couchdb support

Tags: javascript, node.js, indexing, elasticsearch, couchdb

Does elasticsearch client (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) for javascript, support creating indexes for couchdb. with curl we can mention couchdb type when creating index as follows:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_river/user_idx/_meta" -d "{
  "type": "couchdb",
  "couchdb": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5984,
    "db": "users",
    "filter": null
  },
  "index": {
    "index": "user_idx",
    "type": "users",
    "bulk_size": "100",
    "bulk_timeout": "10ms"
  }
}"
```

But with client.indices.create or client.index, I could not find any option to set couchdb for index. Will appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: This thread might help: https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/issues/210 (it is MongoDB, but the issue sounds similar to yours)

Comment: @dlebech that link looks good. If you change your JSON to match the one in the last comment there, it should work https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/issues/210#issuecomment-34337226